# Is it possible to restore core system files using APT if deleted them accidentally?

Tags: apt, 20.04, files, data-recovery

If I delete any system files accidentally, will those files be restored if I run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` (as root user)?

Comment: If You know from which package the files are You can issue this command to reinstall that package `sudo apt install --reinstall [package]`.

Comment: The answer is no.  Will have to reinstall files if system still works.  If system does not work, an install of whole system might be easiest( lost of all data possible)

Comment: Protecting system files is one good reason you shouldn't be running as the root user in the first place. Ubuntu is designed to use sudo instead to protect you.

Answer (score 1):

No they will NOT be restored, for two reasons:

The packaging system does not know the file you "accidentally" delete is missing. As far as the packaging system is concerned, nothing needs to be updated.

Second, if you "accidentally" delete some system files, you can prevent programs (e.g. `login`, `sudo`, `dpkg`, ... ) from running, so your system could become unrunnable and unfixable.